# Locating specific elements on selenium or checking multiple things on a single element- Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Let's say that I have this code:

```
<li attrib1="attrib1_text" attrib2="attrib2_text" another_attrib = "sometext"> ...
 </li>
```

and I want to find the **attrib1** attribute and the **attrib2** attribute, and returns true if that is correct, for example

```
if attrib1 == "attrib1_text" and attrib2 == "attrib2_text":
    return true
```

something like this is what I have tried:

```
domain_test = '//*[contains(@attrib1, "attrib1_text" and @attrib2, "attrib2_text")]'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
try:
   elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(domain_test)
   return True
except NoSuchElementException:
   return False
```

However, it returns False when it should return True

Comment: Can you share the website?

Answer (score 0):

Try simply to replace this predicate

```
[contains(@attrib1, "attrib1_text" and @attrib2, "attrib2_text")]
```

with this

```
[contains(@attrib1, "attrib1_text") and contains(@attrib2, "attrib2_text")]
```

or this

```
[@attrib1="attrib1_text" and @attrib2="attrib2_text"]
```